# Asp.Net MVC how to call a method from a instanc of a class by buttonClick event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I made a WakeUp program for my Company and I'm new at ASP.NET.
I´ve got the host class with the strings `dnsName`, `IpAddress`, `MacAddress` and the method `WakeUP()`. Now I need a button, which calls the WakeUP method of the instance of Model[i], by the onButtonClick Event.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model[i].DnsName</td>
        <td>@Model[i].IpAddress</td>
        <td>@Model[i].MacAddress</td>
        <td>
           --> Here I need a button to call the wakeUp() method from Model[i]
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: So `WakeUP` is a method on your `Model`? Server-Side? Then you will need to make a request to the server.

Comment: Your model is just a dto object. You should not call any methods from it. Just implement controller with the action method accepting Model as a parameter,

Comment: <button type="button" id="Button" onclick="location.href ='@Html.Action("SendWakeUp(Model[i])", "Home")'">Wake Up!</button>     I have tried this but it throws a exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your model `Server`, and from the looks of it the view has an array of `Server` (or a `List`, `IEnumerable` etc...). The code below will add an anchor, which will make a `GET` to a route and pass the `Id` of the `Server`, assuming that you got an `Id`. If not, you can pass something else that is unique for the specific `Server`. This is very handy because you don't need to send the entire model, you simply pass the `Id` and let the `Controller` handle that part instead. The `Controller` can fetch the correct `Server` instance based on the `Id`, and then wake it up.

**View:**

```
@model Server[]

<! -- Other stuff -->
<table>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model[i].DnsName</td>
        <td>@Model[i].IpAddress</td>
        <td>@Model[i].MacAddress</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(string.Format("Wake up {0}", Model[i].DnsName), "WakeUp", "Home", new {id = @Model[i].Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**And your controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WakeUp(int id)
    {
        // id will be the id of the server.
        // Do your logic here.

       return View(); // Or whatever you want to return.
    }
}
```

If you *really* need to pass the entire model, you should do a `post` instead. But I don't think you need to, since the model seems to be server-generated and thus not necessary to send back. There's no user input there...

And lastly, you shouldn't have business logic in your model. So the method you're calling `WakeUP()` should not be in the `Server`-object. I think it's better if you do it in a controller, manager or somewhere else, and pass the `Id` to that method. Something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WakeUp(int id)
    {
       // Possibly some validation here?

       // Send the id to the manager.
       var manager = new WakeUpManager();
       manager.WakeUp(id);

       return View(); // Or whatever you want to return.
    }
}

public class WakeUpManager
{
    public void WakeUp(int serverId)
    {
        // Wake the server up... or snooze... or whatever. :)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Desiigner - Cool. Glad I could help. Good luck with your project, and welcome to StackOverflow!